# How to find all combinations of strings character by character

Tags: java

If I have for instance

CAT,

In JAVA, I want all possible combinations of characters with 1 character change at a time (excluding the combination CAT):

```
AAT
BAT
DAT
EAT
.
.
.
ZAT

CBT
CCT
CDT
.
.
.
CZT

CAA
CAB
CAC
.
.
.
CAZ
```

I have this so far :

```
public class alphaTesting
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
   {    
      char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();    

    for(int i = 0 ; i < alphabet.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(alphabet[i] + "\n");
    }

    String word = "cat";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < word.length() ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < alphabet.length ; j++)
        {
            // System.out.println(alphabet[i] + "\n");
            // System.out.println(charAt(i) = )
            word = word.replace(word.charAt(i), alphabet[j]);
            System.out.println(word);
        }       
    }

   }
}
```

These are the first few lines of the output :

```
aat
bbt
cct
ddt
eet
fft
ggt
```

But isn't the inner loop supposed to run all alphabets first, before moving on to word.charAt(1)?

Comment: You've forgotten to post your own attempt at a solution and use this to ask a much more specific question. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
  Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: i apologize. I added my attempt

Comment: Note that method `replace()` in class `String` replaces **all** occurrences. Not appropriate if your word contains the same character more than once. Perhaps better to use class `StringBuilder`. It has method [setCharAt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt-int-char-) for example. But be aware that `String` is immutable and `StringBuilder` is not.

Comment: String word2 = word.replace(word.charAt(i), alphabet[j]);
this worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked

String word2 = "";

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < word.length() ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < alphabet.length ; j++)
                {
                    // show indices
                    System.out.println("i = " + i + " j = " + j);           
                    word2 = word.substring(0,i) + alphabet[j] + word.substring(i+1); ;
                            if (!word2.equals(word) {
                            System.out.println(word2);
                            }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a more elegant code then, the below code should do the job. 
I used a functional library called `vavr` here.
You may want to add it to the dependency.

```
import io.vavr.collection.Stream;
import io.vavr.collection.Traversable;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.ofAll("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray())
                .map(Character::toUpperCase)
                .combinations(3)
                .map(Traversable::mkString)
                .filter(s -> !s.equals("CAT"))
                .take(100)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The `take(100)` takes only first 100 values. You can change it to take as many values as you want or just remove it to get all the values.

*Note*: This is JAVA-8